# In fllipperview childview which added is not working

Tags: android, viewflipper

I have used Flipper.we generally add layout in flipper tag. as below

```
<flipper>
   <LinearLayout1>
   <LinearLayout2>
</flipper>
```

In my program there are three activity which I want to show in flipper(which should flipp one after another.)

each activity perform some task seperately.

when I add that layout file into flipper tag. as below shown,

(this my main xml file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/ViewFlipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/screenxyzf"
        layout="@layout/screenxyz" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/screenabcf"
        layout="@layout/screenabc" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/activity_mainf"
        layout="@layout/activity_main" />
</ViewFlipper>

</LinearLayout>
```

// My Java Code...

```
package com.example.exampledemo3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class Swipe extends Activity {

ViewFlipper flipper;
float lastX;
View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;
LinearLayout chapterMain,chapterAbc,chapterXyz;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.swipe);
    flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.ViewFlipper);
    /*chapterMain=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_mainf);
    chapterAbc=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.screenabcf);
    chapterXyz=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.screenxyzf);*/

    flipper.setDisplayedChild(R.id.activity_mainf);
    flipper.setDisplayedChild(R.id.screenabcf);
    flipper.setDisplayedChild(R.id.screenxyzf);     


}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {

    switch (touchevent.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        lastX = touchevent.getX();
        break;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        float currentX = touchevent.getX();
        if (lastX < currentX) {
            if (flipper.getDisplayedChild() == 0)
                break;
            flipper.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_from_left);
            flipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_to_right);
            flipper.showNext();
        }
        if (lastX > currentX) {
            if (flipper.getDisplayedChild() == 1)
                break;
            flipper.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_from_right);
            flipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_to_left);
            flipper.showPrevious();
        }
        break;
    }
    }
    return false;
}
 }
```

now in my code the flipper is working fine but the activities which I want to show in Flipper is not working(Activites are not working,means the listview is not loading data,the button,textview are visible but dont support to any event).

Can anyone tell me what should I do..?

Comment: can u post your code about include tag?just append in question

Comment: @Pratik: I have added the code. screenxyz.xml,screenabc.xml & activity_main.xml are my layout files.

Comment: @Guddu What do you mean under "is not working", they are not shown on screen or what?

Comment: Make sure you are using LinearLayout as your main layout for these three layouts and it's width and height is fill_parent.

Comment: @pratik:all views are visible. but as its functionality is not working.If I write directly layout into flipper tag then its works fine but the code become complicated.so I want use this include tag.

Comment: @Maulik: I have used LinearLayout with height and width fill-parent.

Comment: @Guddu Then try to add id for that particular include tag as said by Fat Dog 47.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Have you created "screenxyz.xml" and "screenabc.xml" files and filled their contents ?**
2. You must set `android:id` for each include or else those will be useless.
3. You can safety remove LinearLayout if there is no other View except ViewFlipper.

Check out this:

```
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ViewFlipper"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

<include layout="@layout/screenxyz"
    android:id="@+id/xyzView" />
<include layout="@layout/activity_main" 
    android:id="@+id/mainView" />
<include layout="@layout/screenabc" 
    android:id="@+id/abcView" />

</ViewFlipper>
```

Comment: yap, i.e. findViewById(R.id.xyzview);

Comment: I have written seperate java file for each layout.
should I write that all code in one java file..
then how I used the subview of that layout...

ok thanks you sir first I try in this way...
you have given me one way to think.
Thank you sir

Comment: Use separated .java files for difference activities, not for different views. With the help of `setDisplayedChild()` which receives an integer starting from 0, you can set which view child ( _include_ ) to be displayed.

Comment: still it is not working 
my code is :-

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.swipe);
flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.ViewFlipper);
flipper.setDisplayedChild(R.id.activity_mainf);
flipper.setDisplayedChild(R.id.screenabcf);
flipper.setDisplayedChild(R.id.screenxyzf); }

Comment: Your initial question was something else, please update your current question with the above code (so everyone can clearly see your code) instead of putting your code in the comments section. I'll check it.